# How to unit test Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

While exploring how to unit test a Kafka Stream I came across `ProcessorTopologyTestDriver`, unfortunately this class seems to have gotten broken with version `0.10.1.0` ([KAFKA-4408](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4408))

Is there a work around available for the KTable issue?

I saw the "Mocked Streams" project but first it uses version `0.10.2.0`, while I'm on `0.10.1.1` and second it is Scala, while my tests are Java/Groovy.

Any help here on how to unit test a stream without having to bootstrap zookeeper/kafka would be great.

Note: I do have integration tests that use embedded servers, this is for unit tests, aka fast, simple tests.

**EDIT**

Thank you to Ramon Garcia

> For people arriving here in Google searches, please note that the test driver class is now org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver
>
> This class is in the maven package groupId org.apache.kafka, artifactId kafka-streams-test-utils

Comment: `ProcessorTopologyTestDriver` is internal test class and not officially part of the release. The JIRA you mentioned got already fixed -- so you can get the latest version from Github.

Comment: That class is available if the `test` qualifier on the dependency is used. I cannot use the latest version since I must support `0.10.1.1`.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware @Hartimer: Kafka Streams version `0.10.2.0` can be run against `0.10.1.1` Kafka brokers, it's backwards compatible.  So if a broker-side version requirement is what's holding you back on the side of Kafka Streams -- it isn't. ;-)

Comment: Good to know! :) Thanks. However if I see correctly, the fix for the linked issue is tied to version `0.11.0`, which is yet to be released right?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way around this, I'm not sure it is THE answer especially after https://stackoverflow.com/users/4953079/matthias-j-sax comment. In any case, sharing what I have so far...

I completely copied `ProcessorTopologyTestDriver` [from the 0.10.1 branch](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.1/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/test/ProcessorTopologyTestDriver.java) (that's the version I'm using).

To address [KAFKA-4408](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4408) I made `private final MockConsumer<byte[], byte[]> restoreStateConsumer` accessible and moved the chunk `task = new StreamTask(...` to a separate method, e.g. `bootstrap`.

On the setup phase of my test I do the following

```
driver = new ProcessorTopologyTestDriver(config, builder)
ArrayList partitionInfos = new ArrayList();
partitionInfos.add(new PartitionInfo('my_ktable', 1, (Node) null, (Node[]) null, (Node[]) null));
driver.restoreStateConsumer.updatePartitions('my_ktable', partitionInfos);
driver.restoreStateConsumer.updateEndOffsets(Collections.singletonMap(new TopicPartition('my_ktable', 1), Long.valueOf(0L)));
driver.bootstrap()
```

And that's it...

**Bonus**

I also ran into [KAFKA-4461](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4461), fortunately since I copied the whole class I was able to "cherry-pick" the [accepted fix](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/2499) with minor tweaks.

As always feedback is appreciated. Although apparently not an official test class, this driver is proven super useful!

Comment: I guess that the right solution -- that's why I was pointing to the fix... There are plans to release official test drivers -- but not timeline yet -- this should make it easier than.

Comment: org.apache.kafka.test.ProcessorTopologyTestDriver is officially out at least as of 0.11 https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.0/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/test/ProcessorTopologyTestDriver.java

Comment: Thanks a lot for the follow up Dimitry!

Answer (score 2):

For people arriving here in Google searches, please note that the test driver class is now org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver

This class is in the maven package groupId org.apache.kafka, artifactId kafka-streams-test-utils

Comment: Would make more sense to add the version from which this change is made. `1.1.0`